# Upgrading Windows 10 OS form V1607 to anything higher

Tags: windows, windows-10, upgrade

I need to upgrade Windows 10 from v1607 to v1809 or higher, and when executing the executable downloaded by [Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10), it throws error *Cannot upgrade, contact system admin*

- I've also tried using the Media Creation Tool's `setup.exe` and it throws an error *Cannot upgrade from V1607 to 22H2*

All updates for v1607 are installed, and formatting is not the option; is there any other solution to upgrade?

Comment: Download each incremental upgrade (1703,1803,1903,20H2, and 22H2) and mount then launching setup.exe if that doesn’t work then your system cannot be upgraded and thus a clean install is your only option

Comment: [This](https://uupdump.net/known.php?q=1803) can help you download 1803, 1903, 20H2, 21H2, and 22H2 ISOs. Search by their build numbers. Early in Window 10 lifecycle the processor requirements slightly changed right around the third feature update release which of course was (1607) so the fact your system has not been updated in 6 years suggests it’s incompatible with later releases.

Comment: Please do the following: delete the log files `cbs.log` and `dism.log` located within `%WinDir%\Logs\<CBS | DISM>` → Admin terminal: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` → Reboot → `Sfc /Scannow` → Reboot → Retry update, and if it fails, please post within code boxes the `cbs.log` and `dism.log`

Comment: Considering that this installation is over 6 years old and the PC itself presumably even older it is possible that it simply is not technically feasible to go to a newer Windows 10 release. Specific hardware components (that don't have suitable drivers for newer Windows 10 releases) can potentially cause this.

Comment: @Tonny If it wasn't possible, Microsoft would state so somewhere, and until the log files are posted, no one has any clue what's causing this. Generally speaking, it's almost always possible to upgrade a Win10+ OS version to the most recent update for Win10+. The issue likely resides within the Component Store, but until the OP posts the logs, there's no way to know.

Comment: @JW0914 I only suggested this as a possible cause for the issue. Without more detail there is no way to tell for sure..I know for a fact that some very old Nvidia videocards can cause this because of missing DirectX features that Windows 10 requires as of a later version. (IIRC that was introduced with in 2019 so 1807 should still work in that case.)

Comment: Since Windows 10 only has one year before EOL, could you use another OS? E.G., it would take less than1 hour total to download a Linux distro such as Ubuntu, make a bootable USB, and install it. You can even test it for your needs from USB without installation.

Comment: This exact situation happened to me on an old device. Download Win10 1909, extract the ISO to a folder on the desktop, unplug internet cable, run setup.exe from the desktop, allow the machine to finish upgrade while remaining offline until you reach login screen again, return internet cable and then carry on as normal via windows update. Download: https://files.rg-adguard.net/files/4f8aaf4f-4ec0-f5de-abde-3d1598e08c59

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to download ISO installation media for all
the intermediate versions between 1607 and the current one and
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
You may try to jump versions, but you take the risk of going too fast
and failing.

The tool to create the boot media of each version is
[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/).

You may find a description of how to create the ISO using Rufus
in the article
[How to Download Old Windows ISOs Images?](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/how-to-download-old-windows-10-11-iso-versions.html).

[image]

Comment: Those older versions of Windows 10 (in the screenshot) will fail to download. As they are unsupported and have been for awhile. Similar reasons that Windows 7 cannot be downloaded. It appears 1809 is the oldest build that is available based on my research